# jQuery Event slideDown to Slide right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a simple jQuery Event Calendar script. Because I'm no good with jQuery. However when you click on a day with an Event the Event information drops down. I believe I've located the correct piece of code for this function.

```
 function displayEvent() {
  $('tbody.event-calendar td').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.day-event').slideUp('fast');
    var monthEvent = $(this).attr('date-month');
    var dayEvent = $(this).text();
    $('.day-event[date-month="' + monthEvent + '"][date-day="' + dayEvent + '"]').slideDown('fast');
  });
};

/**
 * Close day-event
 */
$('.close').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().slideUp('fast');
});
```

So my question is. How can I make this slide right instead of down? Because of the layout of my Website I'd rather the Event information came out to the right.

Thank you in advance!!

EDIT;

Plugin Link: http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-simple-event-calendar
Github Link: https://github.com/philipehsing/jQuery.Simple-Event-Calendar
Demo: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-Pretty-Event-Calendar-with-jQuery/#

PS: I couldn't get it to show in JsFiddle, not sure why. But you can see with the Demo how it works! I hope this is enough information.

Comment: can you create a fiddle and add the source-code of the plugin so that we can try/play.

Comment: $('.day-event[date-month="' + monthEvent + '"][date-day="' + dayEvent + '"]').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);

Comment: Hi, i've updated the Question with what you have asked for! Travis I tried your input but it didn't change anything; perhaps I pasted the wrong piece of code in the Question! I've added links now though. Thank you :)